# Display records month wise based on other column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following is the data my table contains. I have shared the Queries also how I need the result.
Based on the IPAddress column, I have to count the data and show it by month like with in IP Address and Out Side the IP Address for particular month.

This is the DDL and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE [#IPAddress](
    [DEPTNO] [numeric](2, 0) NULL,
    [HIREDATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [IPAddress] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]    
GO

INSERT [dbo].[#IPAddress] ([DEPTNO], [HIREDATE], [IPAddress]) 
VALUES (CAST(20 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x0000738200000000 AS DateTime), 14)    
, (CAST(30 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x000073C300000000 AS DateTime), 6)    
, (CAST(30 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x000073C500000000 AS DateTime), 18)    
, (CAST(20 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x000073EC00000000 AS DateTime), 1)    
, (CAST(30 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x0000749F00000000 AS DateTime), 13)    
, (CAST(30 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x0000740900000000 AS DateTime), 9)    
, (CAST(10 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x0000743000000000 AS DateTime), 1)    
, (CAST(20 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x0000765400000000 AS DateTime), 13)    
, (CAST(10 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x000074D100000000 AS DateTime), 15)    
, (CAST(30 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x0000748B00000000 AS DateTime), 19)    
, (CAST(20 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x0000767600000000 AS DateTime), 12)    
, (CAST(30 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x000074E100000000 AS DateTime), 1)    
, (CAST(20 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x000074E100000000 AS DateTime), 1)    
, (CAST(10 AS Numeric(2, 0)), CAST(0x0000751400000000 AS DateTime), 2)
```

My requirement is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
select DEPTNO, datename(month,HIREDATE) [month],COUNT(IPAddress) Amount from [#IPAddress] where IPAddress between 1 and 10 group by DEPTNO,datename(month,HIREDATE)
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount) FOR [month] IN (December,February,January,November,September)
)AS pvt

SELECT *
FROM (
select DEPTNO, datename(month,HIREDATE) [month],COUNT(IPAddress) Amount from [#IPAddress] where IPAddress between 11 and 20 group by DEPTNO,datename(month,HIREDATE)
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount) FOR [month] IN (December,February,January,November,September)
)AS pvt
```

After Executing above queries I am getting 2 result sets.

But I would like the data similar to -

```
select 10 DeptNo,null DecemberInIPAddress,null DecemberOutIPAddress,null FebruaryInIPAddress,null FebruaryOutIPAddress,1 JanuaryInIPAddress,null JanuaryOutIPAddress,
null NovemberInIPAddress,1 NovemberOutIPAddress, null SeptemberInIPAddress,null SeptemberOutIPAddress 
union
select 20 DeptNo,1 DecemberInIPAddress,2 DecemberOutIPAddress,null FebruaryInIPAddress,null FebruaryOutIPAddress,null JanuaryInIPAddress,1 JanuaryOutIPAddress,
null NovemberInIPAddress,null NovemberOutIPAddress, null SeptemberInIPAddress,null SeptemberOutIPAddress 
union
    select 30 DeptNo,1 DecemberInIPAddress,null DecemberOutIPAddress,1 FebruaryInIPAddress,1 FebruaryOutIPAddress,null JanuaryInIPAddress,null JanuaryOutIPAddress,
    null NovemberInIPAddress,null NovemberOutIPAddress, null SeptemberInIPAddress,2 SeptemberOutIPAddress
```

Final query giving one result set, I want result like that.

Comment: So why can't you get what you want?    Are you getting an error?   Please post your attempt, and what's wrong with it.

Comment: How are you determining what is `IN` and `OUT` IP address?

Comment: @Tab Alleman, Actually the month names are dynamic. But I have hard coded here.

Comment: @ FutbolFan, they given me range of IPAddress. If it is between, then inside the Country, else Out side.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired output, you could easily use your two queries and do a join on `DeptNo` like this:

```
;WITH in_IPaddress
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT DEPTNO
            ,datename(month, HIREDATE) [month]
            ,IPAddress
        FROM [#IPAddress]
        WHERE IPaddress BETWEEN 1 AND 10
        ) AS s
    PIVOT(COUNT(IPAddress) FOR [month] IN (December,February,January,November,September)
    ) AS pvt
    ),
out_IPAddress
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT DEPTNO
            ,datename(month, HIREDATE) [month]
            ,IPAddress
        FROM [#IPAddress]
        WHERE IPaddress BETWEEN 11 AND 20
        ) AS s
    PIVOT(COUNT(IPAddress) FOR [month] IN (December,February,January,November,September)
    ) AS pvt
    )
SELECT 
      i.deptno
    ,i.December AS DecemberInIp
    ,o.December AS DecemberOutIp
    ,i.February AS FebruaryInIp
    ,o.February AS FebruaryOutIp
    ,i.January AS JanuaryInIp
    ,o.January AS JanuaryOutIp
    ,i.November AS NovemberInIp
    ,o.November AS NovemberOutIp
    ,i.September AS SeptemberInIp
    ,o.September AS SeptemberOutIp
FROM in_IPAddress i
LEFT JOIN out_IPAddress o ON i.deptNO = o.DeptNo;
```

[**Code Demo**](http://rextester.com/XTISXT25194)

On a side, I tweaked your pivot query as well: removed the `group by` and instead of `sum` on `IPAddress`, I used `count` instead. Also, you may notice that the output result is returning 0's instead of null values which can be easily replaced using `case when' statement in your outer query.

**UPDATE:**

Since your column name are not static, you would need to use dynamic pivot to build them. Also, instead of joining your column name to conditional `in` and `out`, I would create another column called `in_out_flag` to distinguish the months.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(datename(month,c.hiredate)) 
            FROM [dbo].[#IPAddress] c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT DEPTNO, In_Out_Flag, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select DEPTNO
                ,case 
                    when IPaddress between 1 and 10
                        then ''In''
                else ''Out''
                end as in_out_flag
                ,datename(month,HIREDATE) [month]
                ,IPAddress  
                from [#IPAddress] 
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 count(IPAddress)
                for [month] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

[**Dynamic Pivot Demo**](http://rextester.com/AIOW41130)

Comment: My Column Names are month names. Those also getting dynamically with date range parameters.

Comment: I didn't see that information in your original question. I would think that would be an important part of your question.